# Compare two lists in python where the elements are in different order

Tags: python

I have multiple lists e.g.

```
list1=[1,4,5]
list2=[4,1,5]
list3=[1,5,4]
```

two lists are considered same if they have the same elements. 
Also the lists can be nested lists

```
list1=[[1,4],5,4]
list2=[5,4,[1,4]]
```

How do i compare them?

Comment: It depends on how you define "same".

Comment: I suppose `list2=[5,4,[4,1]]` should also compare equal to `list1`? But `list2=[5,4,4,[1,4]]` shouldn't? It looks like you need to recursively sort the lists before comparing them.

Comment: @lightalchemist same is defined if the lists contain the same elements..

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes, they are same if they have the same number of elements in any order. The nested ones inside will not be in any different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `flatten` your lists then use `set` to keep the unique elements then compare :

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> list1=[[1,4],5,4]
>>> list2=[5,4,[1,4]]
>>> set(flatten(list1))==set(flatten(list2))
True
```

Comment: @karsa Would this cause them to be equal if list2 was defined as `[5,4,[1,4], 4]`?

Comment: @AndrewFarber so the result would be `False`

Comment: @Kasra: It is prudent to use set instead of sorted when comparing inclusive comparison.

Comment: @Abhijit yeah sure, i was  thinking about this point! thanks for reminding ;)

Comment: How do i extend this to multiple lists?

Comment: @rrgirish you need to use `set` and `flatten` for all of them and then compare them! ;)